# In azure logic App how to create a 10 integer digit unique id

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps, uniqueidentifier

In azure logic App how to create a 10 digit unique id per request. Currently, I am using Function Javascript but it is creating duplicates.

JAVAscript funaction is:

```
a=1000000000;

module.exports = function (context, req) {
    context.log('JavaScript HTTP trigger function processed a request.');
    a=a+1;
    if (true) {
        context.res = {
            // status: 200, /* Defaults to 200 */
            body: a
        };
    }
    else {
        context.res = {
            status: 400,
            body: "Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body"
        };
    }
    context.done();
};
```

how to solve this

Comment: there is a `guid()` function https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#guid but it is not a 10 digit uid.

Comment: Yeah i used that one first then I changed because it is too long

Comment: How about use `a = Math.floor(Math.random()*9000000000) + 1000000000` to create a random 10 digit integer. Although it could be duplicated, but the chance is minimal

Comment: @VikramAS What do you mean too long ? it is hard to generate a unique identifer. otherwise store you increment in a file/database if you dont want to have duplicated.

Comment: yeah I know but I want integer number as in backend system already  they have defined id as integer so while integrating this is the problem i'm facing

Comment: Use the result from `guid()` as a seed in your random number generator, that way you're (almost) guaranteed to not end up with duplicates. You should have a chat with your backend guys, that's no way to guarantee unique IDs, UUID/GUIDs are ugly for a good reason!

Answer (score 3):

1. The proper way would be to use something like `guid` as recommended by @Thomas but it sounds like it would have to be a separate conversation with your back-end guys.
2. Another approach is to define some sort of formula using `rand()` together with salting methods to really try minimize the chance of duplication.
3. The third approach, which i think fits better in your scenario, is to use `unix timestamp` which would give you 10 digit unique integer that will increment in seconds.

Perhaps, you could use #3 and salt it with #2 to minimize any duplication as well so that the `uniqueness` is more time-bound.

Comment: Thank you for the answer I've already implemented with the timestamp approach, yeah the problem is the increment in second.

Answer (score 3):

You could just access the numeric run identifier for the logic app request which is unique per request anyway and will be available to your logic app request context. It is a rather long numeric string (longer than 10 digits). However, as it is numeric you could re-encode and shorten it.

The run identifier is accessed via: **@workflow()['run']['name']**

e.g. if the run identifier is 08586676754160363885 when compressed as base 64 it would be Y29tcHJlc3M= (This is 12 characters)

If you needed to compress it to 10 characters you could compress it to base 72 or more.